# A Mess of Missions

Tags: java, game, libgdx

I've mostly completed the prototype for my [city building simulation](http://www.pixelpocalypse.com/voxelcity), and now I have added the meta-game mission system to the game. You see these mission systems in a great many games these days.  The basic idea is that the player is assigned a mission at the start of the game, such as `Build 50 Industrial buildings`, and once completed gains a permanent bonus that will apply in all future games.

Programming this turned out to be pretty complicated (at least as far as the number of classes goes) so I think a review of the code will be helpful.  I have an abstract `MayorMission` class, and then a few different implementations of that depending on the mission requirements. Some of them take a value for the type of building required to complete the mission, or for example the type of zone, or number of people or money required.  I feel like multiple classes here is a good idea because it simplifies the code for checking whether missions are completed, but I wonder if I have taken things too far.

**MayorMission.java**

```
public abstract class MayorMission {

    public final int targetNumber;
    public final World world;
    public final String name;
    public final PlayerAbility reward;

    public boolean isComplete;

    public MayorMission(int targetNumber, World world, String name, PlayerAbility reward) {
        this.targetNumber = targetNumber;
        this.world = world;
        this.name = name;
        this.reward = reward;
    }

    public abstract boolean checkIfComplete();
}
```

**IsoTileTypeMission.java**

```
public class IsoTileTypeMission extends MayorMission {

    private final IsoTileType typeRequired;

    public IsoTileTypeMission(int targetNumber, World world, IsoTileType typeRequired, String name, PlayerAbility reward) {
        super(targetNumber, world, name, reward);
        this.typeRequired = typeRequired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkIfComplete() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Tile[] row : this.world.levelData) {
            for (Tile tile : row) {
                if (tile.getBuildingType() == typeRequired) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count >= this.targetNumber;
    }
}
```

**ZoneTypeLevelMission.java**

```
public class ZoneTypeLevelMission extends MayorMission {

    private final int levelRequired;

    public ZoneTypeLevelMission(int targetNumber, World world, int levelRequired, String name, PlayerAbility reward) {
        super(targetNumber, world, name, reward);
        this.levelRequired = levelRequired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkIfComplete() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Tile[] row : this.world.levelData) {
            for (Tile tile : row) {
                if (tile.zoneType.getLevel() >= levelRequired) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count >= this.targetNumber;
    }
}
```

**ZoneTypeMission**

```
public class ZoneTypeMission extends MayorMission {

    List<ZoneType> targetTypes;

    public ZoneTypeMission(int targetNumber, World world, List<ZoneType> targetTypes, String name, PlayerAbility reward) {
        super(targetNumber, world, name, reward);
        this.targetTypes = targetTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkIfComplete() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Tile[] row : this.world.levelData) {
            for (Tile tile : row) {
                if (this.targetTypes.contains(tile.zoneType)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count >= this.targetNumber;
    }
}
```

**WorldPopMission.java**

```
public class WorldPopMission extends MayorMission {

    private final int targetPop;

    public WorldPopMission(World world, int targetPop, String name, PlayerAbility reward) {
        super(0, world, name, reward);
        this.targetPop = targetPop;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkIfComplete() {
        int currentPop = this.world.getPopulation();
        for (Tile[] row : this.world.levelData) {
            for (Tile tile : row) {
                currentPop += tile.getPopulation();
            }
        }
        return currentPop >= this.targetPop;
    }
}
```

**MoneyMission.java**

```
public class MoneyMission extends MayorMission {

    public MoneyMission(int targetNumber, World world, String name,
            PlayerAbility reward) {
        super(targetNumber, world, name, reward);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkIfComplete() {
        return this.world.currentMoney >= this.targetNumber;
    }
}
```

**MaxPopMission.java**

```
public class MaxPopMission extends MayorMission{

    public MaxPopMission(int targetNumber, World world, String name, PlayerAbility reward) {
        super(targetNumber, world, name, reward);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkIfComplete() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Tile[] row : this.world.levelData) {
            for (Tile tile : row) {
                if (tile.getPopulation() >= tile.getMaxPopulation()) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count >= this.targetNumber;
    }
}
```

**DesireMission.java**

```
public class DesireMission extends MayorMission {

    private final int targetDesire;

    public DesireMission(int targetNumber, World world, int targetDesire, String name, PlayerAbility reward) {
        super(targetNumber, world, name, reward);
        this.targetDesire = targetDesire;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkIfComplete() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Tile[] row : this.world.levelData) {
            for (Tile tile : row) {
                if (tile.desire >= this.targetDesire) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count >= this.targetNumber;
    }
}
```

Here is the example creation of missions:

```
public List<MayorMission> getAllMissions() {
    List<MayorMission> missions = new ArrayList<MayorMission>();
    missions.add(new ZoneTypeMission(50, this.world, ZoneType.getResidentialZones(), "Build 50 Residential", PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_RES_1));
    missions.add(new ZoneTypeMission(50, this.world, ZoneType.getCommercialZones(), "Build 50 Commercial", PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_COM_1));
    missions.add(new ZoneTypeMission(50, this.world, ZoneType.getIndustrialZones(), "Build 50 Industrial", PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_IND_1));

    missions.add(new ZoneTypeLevelMission(50, this.world, 1, "Build 50 Light Zones", PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_RES_2));
    missions.add(new ZoneTypeLevelMission(100, this.world, 1, "Build 100 Light Zones", PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_COM_2));
    missions.add(new ZoneTypeLevelMission(50, this.world, 2, "Build 50 Medium Zones", PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_IND_2));
    missions.add(new ZoneTypeLevelMission(100, this.world, 2, "Build 100 Medium Zones", PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_RES_3));
    missions.add(new ZoneTypeLevelMission(50, this.world, 3, "Build 50 Heavy Zones", PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_COM_3));
    missions.add(new ZoneTypeLevelMission(100, this.world, 3, "Build 100 Heavy Zones", PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_IND_3));

    missions.add(new MoneyMission(100000, this.world, "Save 100000 dollars", PlayerAbility.HIGHER_TAXES));

    missions.add(new WorldPopMission(this.world, 7500, "Have 7500 people", PlayerAbility.BONUS_POPULATION));

    missions.add(new DesireMission(50, this.world, 75, "Have 50 tiles with 75 desire", PlayerAbility.CHEAPER_HEAVY_ZONE));

    //missions.add(new ZoneTypeMission(50, this.world, ZoneType.getUtilityZones(), "Build 50 Utility", null));
    //missions.add(new ZoneTypeMission(15, this.world, ZoneType.getSpecialZones())); //arcos
    //missions.add(new IsoTileTypeMission(50, this.world, IsoTileType.PARK, "Build 50 parks", null));
    //missions.add(new IsoTileTypeMission(20, this.world, IsoTileType.FUN, "Build 20 casinos", null));
    //missions.add(new MaxPopMission(20, this.world, "Have 20 max population tiles", null));
    //missions.add(new ZoneTypeLevelMission(World.WORLD_HEIGHT * World.WORLD_WIDTH, this.world, 1, "Cover map in light zones", null));

    return missions;
}
```

And here is the simple check to see whether they are completed. This runs every cycle because not all missions are completed under the same type of conditions.

```
private void checkIfMissionComplete() {
    if (this.game.getPlayer().assignedMission.checkIfComplete()) {
        this.game.getPlayer().assignedMission.isComplete = true;
    }
}
```

If you would like to try the prototype, here it is: [VoxelCity](http://www.pixelpocalypse.com/voxelcity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's several things to address here, so let's get to it!

**Classes**

Too many.

**Speed**

Can be better.

**Declaring missions**

Perfect for a config file.

**checkIfMissionComplete**

Slight code duplication.

---

#### Classes

[BEEP BEEP BEEP Strategy pattern!](http://altreus.github.io/qi-klaxon/?Strategy+Pattern)

This bothers me a bit:

```
super(targetNumber, world, name, reward);
```

Instead of having that, I would use a `MayorMission` constructor like this:

```
public MayorMission(int targetNumber, World world, String name,
    PlayerAbility reward, GameGoal goal)
```

Where `GameGoal` is something like:

```
public interface GameGoal {
     boolean checkIfComplete();
}
```

This reduces the need to subclass `MayorMission` and let's you use *composition over inheritance*. This might also lead to the possibility of removing some of the arguments from the constructor.

The different `GameGoal` objects can then either be implemented as pure classes, or constructed using factory methods and anonymous inner classes.

So instead of:

```
missions.add(new ZoneTypeMission(50, this.world, 
     ZoneType.getResidentialZones(), "Build 50 Residential", 
     PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_RES_1));
```

We might end up with:

```
missions.add(new MayorMission(this.world, "Build 50 Residential", 
     PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_RES_1,
     zoneTypeGoal(50, ZoneType.getResidentialZones())));
```

Or how about:

```
missions.add(world.createMission("Build 50 Residential",
     PlayerAbility.UNLOCK_RES_1, 
     zoneTypeGoal(50, ZoneType.getResidentialZones()));
```

#### Generic tile scanning

Many of your mission goals depends on a sum of all tiles (when purely counting, the value for each tile matching the predicate is 1)

This leads to a possibilty of:

```
public class CountingGoal implements GameGoal {
    private final ToIntFunction<Tile> tileValue;

    @Override
    public boolean checkIfComplete() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Tile[] row : world.levelData) {
            for (Tile tile : row) {
                sum += tileValue.applyAsInt(tile);
            }
        }
        return sum >= targetNumber;
    }
}
```

`ToIntFunction` is an interface that exists in Java 8, but as you're not using Java 8 you have to declare it yourself:

```
public interface ToIntFunction<T> {
     int applyAsInt(T obj);
}
```

This will allow you to extract implementations, such as:

```
new ToIntFunction<Tile>() {
    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(Tile tile) {
        return tile.getBuildingType() == typeRequired ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Or, the class version of that:

```
class BuildingTypeCounting implements ToIntFunction<Tile> {
    private final BuildingType typeRequired;

    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(Tile tile) {
        return tile.getBuildingType() == typeRequired ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

#### Speed

Looping over each and every tile in the game is a bit slow. You might want to consider keeping track of the zones that actually have some content on them. You can do this by using a `List<Tile> residential`, or perhaps even `Map<ZoneType, List<Tile>> tilesByType`, or if there are generally a lot of empty tiles, perhaps `List<Tile> tilesWithBuildings` would be enough.

You might want to consider splitting your world data structure so that general tile data is kept as a two-dimensional array, and objects that do something are kept in a `List`.

#### `checkIfMissionComplete`

```
private void checkIfMissionComplete() {
    if (this.game.getPlayer().assignedMission.checkIfComplete()) {
        this.game.getPlayer().assignedMission.isComplete = true;
    }
}
```

It feels like it is the mission's job to mark itself as completed, and then it may return true if it did mark it as completed.

```
private void checkIfMissionComplete() {
    this.game.getPlayer().assignedMission.markIfCompleted();
}
```

And in the `MayorMission`:

```
public boolean markIfCompleted() {
    boolean completed = this.checkIfComplete();
    if (completed) {
        this.isComplete = true;
    }
    return completed;
}
```